# How to set reveal view in pre lollipop version in android

Tags: java, android

I am using reveal view in my application.. but reveal view is not support on pre lollipop version... how to support reveal view in pre lollipop version

Comment: you should check this library https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal

Comment: thank you friend..if any possible to support API 8

Comment: i had only 14+ in suggestions sorry!

Comment: ok.thank you # jaydeep patel